# MacVim：日本語・英語でカーソルの色を変える方法

Tags: vim

MacVim 8.2.539 (163)
macOS 10.15.4 Calalina

**＜目的＞**
日本語・英語でカーソルの色を変えたい。

**＜現状＞**
インターネット上にある情報を参考に以下のコードを`.gvimrc`に入れて試しましたが，カーソルの色は変わりません。

（メインコード）

```
*****
  highlight Cursor guifg=NONE guibg=Green
  highlight CursorIM guifg=NONE guibg=Purple
endif
```

上のメインコードの******を以下の３つのパターンをトライしました。
1. `if has('xim')`
2. `if has('multi_byte_ime')`
3. `if has('xim') || has('multi_byte_ime')`

解決方法をご教示いただけると非常に助かります。

Comment: if ... endif をなくして、中身の highlight ... の2行のみにするとどうですか？

Comment: 色は変わりませんでした。

Comment: vim起動後に手動で`:highlight CursorIM guifg=NONE guibg=Purple`をコマンドで実行し、日英を変えたら、カーソルの色が変わりますか？これでも変わらなければ、使ってるmacvimが対応してないかもしれないですね。

Comment: 変わりませんでした。対応していないということのようですね。実は[MacVim-Kaoriya](https://github.com/splhack/macvim-kaoriya)を使っていたのですが，アップデートがなかったので[vim-jp](https://vim-jp.org)からダウンロードして使ってみました。残念です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントで教えて頂いた内容を参考に Vim 起動後に以下のコマンドを実行し、日英を切り替えたらカーソルの色が変わるかを確認してみました。

```
:highlight CursorIM guifg=NONE guibg=Purple
```

[MacVim-Kaoriya](https://github.com/splhack/macvim-kaoriya) の環境では上記コマンドでも色が変わらないため、現時点では対応していないようです。

アップデートがなかったので代わりに [vim-jp](https://vim-jp.org) からダウンロードして使ってみました。

---

*この投稿は [@todashuta さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66543/macvim-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e-%e8%8b%b1%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%a7%e3%82%ab%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bd%e3%83%ab%e3%81%ae%e8%89%b2%e3%82%92%e5%a4%89%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95#comment73099_66543) と [@T_T さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66543/macvim-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e-%e8%8b%b1%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%a7%e3%82%ab%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bd%e3%83%ab%e3%81%ae%e8%89%b2%e3%82%92%e5%a4%89%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95#comment73100_66543) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*